# Extracting text from PDF in Python

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I have a PDF full of quotes:

https://www.pdf-archive.com/2017/03/22/test/

I can extract the text in python using the following code:

```
import PyPDF2

pdfFileObj = open('example.pdf','rb') 
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)         
print (pageObj.extractText())
```

This returns all the quotes as one paragraph. Is it possible to 'split' the pdf by the horizontal separator and split it into quotes that way?

Comment: Can you please provide example of a text and an example of how you want it to look.

Comment: The link will go to the PDF.  In this PDF there are two phrases. I am looking to extract the two phrases/quotes into two string variables which I will then process further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just extract the quotes from the pdf text you can use `regex` to find all the quotes.

```
import PyPDF2
import re
pdfFileObj = open('test.pdf','rb') 
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)         
text = str(pageObj.extractText())

quotes = re.findall(r'"[^"]*"',text)
for quote in quotes:
    print quote
    print
```

or just

```
quotes = re.findall(r'"[^"]*"',text)
print quotes
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that. It seems to be working. Could you explain the regex? I can't quite make sense of it. My main goal is extracting https://www.pdf-archive.com/2017/03/22/pdf/ maybe you could have a quick look at that. I thought I might be able to learn from this pdf but not sure if I can.

Comment: what do you want to extract from the pdf actually ? there are no quotes and totally different from your question.

Comment: The end goal is JSON pairs of reference, date, applicant, location and proposal. I did up the other pdf to try and learn to then apply it to the main pdf but I don't think the code is  transferrable .

Answer (score 0):

i could not find a way to split it by the horizontal separator, but i managed to do it in another way:

```
import PyPDF2

quotes = []

pdfFileObj = open('test.pdf','rb') 
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)         
for x in (pageObj.extractText()).split('"\n'): print x+"\n"*5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pdfplumber

pdf = pdfplumber.open(file_path)

p0 = pdf.pages[0]

text = p0.extract_text()

text
```

Comment: Add context around your answer for future learning purpose and downvote prevention. (From Review).